# spyder seaborn import module macbook

Tags: python, import, module, spyder, seaborn

I'm using spyder (python2.7) on a macbook for my data analysis

```
import seaborn as sis
```

but when I run:

```
ImportError: No module named seaboard
```

I installed seaborn using conda install seaborn and also pip2.7, but still having trouble in spyder. If run in terminal as `python2.7 file.py`it works, so I guess I'm not able to import seaborn correctly in spyder.

**PS:**
I've also tried adding the right path where the package is located into python path manager.....

Thank you very much

Comment: Your example code doesn't match the text in the error message, so you've typed something wrong somewhere. It's important to post your exact code and the exact error message, otherwise we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda install:
http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html

```
conda install seaborn
```

You should use conda for easy step, or follow this tutorial:

https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/installing.html